# Convert from ULong to Integer

Tags: vb.net, numbers, implicit-conversion

I´m trying to convert a list of ULONG into an array of Integers.

The problem is related to HOW discard the MSB of ULONG! I had tried all kind of operations and all of them are raising an "Overflow Exception" error:

```
dim MyInteger as Integer = CInt(ULong_Number)     
dim MyInteger as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ULong_Number)
dim MyInteger as Integer = Convert.ToUInt32(ULong_Number) 
dim MyInteger as Integer = ULong_Number xor &HFFFFFFFF00000000 xor &HFFFFFFFF00000000
```

I´m trying to avoid a convertion into a temporary byte array to, after, read each 4 bytes into the integer (the LIST if huge, almost 2 million numbers).

Does anyone have any idea to implicit convert this ULONG to INTEGER?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're expecting as a result?

Comment: I expect just the last 32-bits portion of each 64-bit number. Or even to convert it into an UINT16 or UINT32, even of rounding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the value of `ULong_Number` is not more than the maximum value of an integer (2^31 - 1, or &H7FFFFFFF), or you want to ignore any higher order bits (which would be an odd thing to do, but you **are** trying to fit an 8-byte number into 4 bytes), you could use this.

```
Dim MyInteger As Integer = CInt(ULong_Number And CULng(&H000000007FFFFFFF))
```

Comment: The problem is that all values are greater than an INTEGER or UINT16. I would like to discard the MSB and get just the last 32 bits of each ULONG. Or even adapt the number (rounding) through an internal convertion function.

Comment: @DavidBS Do you mean some of the `Long` numbers are between &H7FFFFFFF and &FFFFFFFF and you want to treat them as negative `Integer`s?

Comment: Blackwood response fits your requirement, i.e. discard the MSB. But, I confirm that it is a strange decision, unless the ulong stores a list of bool (or bool arrays).

Comment: I don´t want to treat them as negative - I just need to get the last 32-bits (or 16-bits in some specific cases).  Thank you!

Comment: Yes Blackwood, your formula seems to help me. IN fact, I was using "XOR" but without the implicit convertion to CULng() - I don´t know why VB.NET does not simply understand the XOR without that implicit command.  Thank you very much!

Comment: if your ulong is MaxValue is -1 , i.e. &HFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. what result do you expect when converting it to int : either -1 (i.e. &HFFFFFFFFFF or max int value (i.e. &H7FFFFFFFFF).

Comment: I expect always a positive number (eg. the Int.MaxValue).

Comment: If you just need to read the bits from the ULONG, then use bitconverter to read the values into a byte array. If later you need a certain integer from certain bytes that array, convert the corresponding bytes into an integer.

Comment: if always expecting a positive number (eg. the Int.MaxValue), Blackwood response is perfect.